# Passing params Hash in methods in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following code in the controller

```
def show 

    client = GameAccounts::GameAccountsClient.new 

    ..

    json = client.get_accounts( ..)
    ..
    end
```

I have the following code in GameAccountsClient

```
def get_accounts(..)
      response = query_account(CGI.escape(params[:name])
      JSON.parse(response.body)
    end
```

I have the above code and i am not sure how to pass params[:name] while calling the get_accounts method in the controller. Can anyone help me out with passing the hash's in methods in rails ? .Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it correctly, you just need to pass the `params[:name]` to your model method.

```
def show
  client = GameAccounts::GameAccountsClient.new
  json = client.get_accounts(params[:name])
end

def get_accounts(name)
  response = query_account(CGI.escape(name)
  JSON.parse(response.body)
end
```